# Loading matlab files using Python's scipy (from a Google Cloud bucket)

Tags: python, matlab, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to run a Keras multi-layer perceptron model using Google Cloud ML engine (following the format put forward in tutorials such as https://github.com/clintonreece/keras-cloud-ml-engine and http://liufuyang.github.io/2017/04/02/just-another-tensorflow-beginner-guide-4.html) and my dataset is in the form of .mat files (which as far as I know are not 7.3 format, so don't need HDF5).

The training set files are in a file called "data" in a Google Cloud storage bucket called project_1; I also have them stored locally. I modified my model for cloud use such that it loads the .mat files as follows:

```
    def train_model (train_file='data', job_dir='./tmp/mlp2', **args):

         with file_io.FileIO(train_file + '/train_subject01.mat', mode='r') as a:
                  train_data = scipy.io.loadmat(a)
```

etc.

When I run the model locally using gcloud commands (with --train-file ./data ) it works smoothly. However, when I try to deploy it to run on the cloud using

```
    $ export BUCKET_NAME=project_1
    ....
    > --train-file gs://$BUCKET_NAME/data
```

as seems to be common practice, I get an error message as follows:

```
   The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. 
   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) 
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals 
   File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/mlp2.py", line 195, in <module> train_model(**arguments) 
   File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/mlp2.py", line 39, in train_model train_data = scipy.io.loadmat(a) 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 135, in loadmat matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names) 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 272, in get_variables hdr, next_position = self.read_var_header() 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 232, in read_var_header header = self._matrix_reader.read_header(check_stream_limit) 
   File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 558, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:5684) 
   File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 610, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_header (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:5609) 
   File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 481, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_int8_string (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:4635) 
   File "scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx", line 362, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_element (scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.c:3994) 
   File "scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx", line 55, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.GenericStream.seek (scipy/io/matlab/streams.c:1401) 
   TypeError: seek() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have no idea what this seek() error means! Am I using the right method to load the file, and if so, why is the issue popping up? Is there an alternative way to load the file?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same python and scipy versions in both cases?  You can do `print(scipy.__version__)` to check the scipy version.

Comment: Got it in one - I checked and both were different, so I changed the runtime version to 1.4 and it ran smoothly. Thanks so much!